# How to update application cache when a delete operation is committed in Oracle table?

Tags: java, oracle

I am having an Oracle table which has my application configurations.I load them at my application startup and use it as my application cache. Now i have requirement to update my configuration if there is any Update in the table. I implemented Oracle's CQN database change notification framework via registering with ROW_ID event. It works for Insert and Update. I get row id in notification and do a lookup in the table using Row id and update my cache. Now while deleting a row, Row id in notification is already deleted from my table then how do i know which configuration to be deleted from cache ?  Should i keep row id as key in my cache to do this ? Or any other efficient & safe way to achieve the same.Please suggest. Thanks in advance

Comment: What about Coherence? You can you it as L2 cache in Hibernate.

Comment: Thanks ibre5041 for quick question but i am bound to use Oracle database change notification framework.